# Exception mapper rerouting

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I have a set of jersey exception mapper and today I realized that
google cache wraps my exceptions into UncheckedExecutionException.
Wrapped exceptions bypass my exception mappers.

There is an idea to define another exception mapper for UncheckedExecutionException and inject all my exception mappers, but how to avoid code duplication in dispatching mechanism. The new exception mapper should just shell out the caused exception.

Answer (score 0):

My expected solution was close.
The only trick there is avoiding cycle references in HK2.

```
@Inject
private Provider<ExceptionMappers> mappersProvider;


register(UncheckedExecutionExceptionMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(UncheckedExecutionException exception) {
        log.error("Error {}", exception.getMessage(), exception);
        return mappersProvider.get().findMapping(exception.getCause()).toResponse(exception.getCause());
    }
```